# scrollLeft() not working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have 2 `div's` having `id's` `div_data` and `head` ,each with property `overflow:auto`.I would like to fire an event when I horizontally scroll the `div_data` using horizontal scroll bar,I need to scroll `head` div horizontally.I have used the following code.But it is not working.

```
$('#div_data').scrollLeft($('#head').scrollLeft());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#div_data').scroll(function(){
    $('#head').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: Fixed nghiinfo's fiddle. Hi used class='demo' instead of id='demo' and forgott to change the selector to $('.demo') from $('#demo').

Comment: @ MIvanIsten Can i hide the div #head scroll bar,so that when we scroll the #div_data ,the other scrollbar should hide